# JavaCC: How to print the text of a node?

Tags: java, javacc

Imagine I have following code in my jjt file:

```
void architecture_statement_part() :
{ System.out.println("architecture_statement_part"); }
{
  ( architecture_statement() )*
}
```

I want print the text, which corresponds to the `architecture_statement_part` is printed using the `println` statement.

When something goes wrong with parsing, I will know where exactly to look for the error.

How can I do it?

I tried

```
void architecture_statement() #void :
{ System.out.println("architecture_statement: " + image.toString()); }
```

but it led to a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void architecture_statement() #void :
{ 
    System.out.println("architecture_statement: " + getToken(1)); 
}
```

That's what I was looking for.